Define macro within another macro
I want to define a macro within another macro, in order to save me some repetetive writing.
Currently I have to write this:
MyClass : public Base<MyClass> {
  Value<std::string> testString = value<std::string>(&MyClass::testString, "something");
  // many more values like this
}

And I want to write something like this, in order to reduce the cluttery of the above:
BASE(MyClass) {
  VALUE(std::string, testString, "something");
}

My solution would have been to define two function style macros and BASE and VALUE and within BASE define another constant named __CURRENT_CLASS that will be used for all calls of VALUE. But how do I define this constant within the BASE macro?

If you want to save some repetitive writing, get a keystroke utility that allows you to write a bunch of text with a single keystroke.  Or make real functions.  The typedef and using are good ways to make synonyms (when using templates, arrays or other data structures).  Macros are evil.

You should also take some keyboarding classes to help improve your typing speed.  Software development involves a lot of typing (not only code, but comments and documentation).

There are applications that can take UML or Flowcharts and generate code from them.  My short cut is to use stencil files and I even wrote my own code generator.  Doesn't help when debugging or fixing issues.

@ThomasMatthews Your comment about keyboarding is arrogant. You have no idea about the OP's typing skills. Software development involves a lot of thinking in the first place, and that is what they practice.

In the code you show, you're not defining a macro inside a macro (which is not possible). You're not even using a macro inside a macro. All you're doing is expanding two different macros individually, complete without any kind or relation or knowledge about each other. You're not even expanding VALUE as part of an argument to the BASE macro. So there's really not much to think about. Except that using macros this way, while not uncommon, tend to make the code harder to understand and maintain, and sooner or later turn into a mess.

Also, #undef your macro names before you #define them, to eliminate possible conflicting macros from headers.

__CURRENT_CLASS is a reserved identifier.

My first thought was "Why macros? why not use variadic templates?".

@DYZ Yeah, I may be arrogant after taking keyboarding classes to improve my typing speed.  Using functions or subroutines so I don't have to repeat code.  Yeah, I find those #define ll long long and other statements appalling.  Years of coding guidelines and code reviews rejecting the synonym and abbreviation macros that make understanding or read code more difficult.  Spending countless hours of debugging due to faulty macros.  Macros are evil.  Typing is an essential skill for software developers, designers architects and documentors.

@Brainiac the syntax you want with the macros is not possible, mainly because of the trailing { after BASE(MyClass). If you moved the { inside BASE() then it can define additional class members. In any case, what is value<std::string>(&MyClass::testString, ...) supposed to be doing, exactly? Why are you passing a pointer to a Value that is still being constructed? What does Value actually look like?

This looks like a XY problem with a misguided attempt at saving some keystrokes, which makes the question doubly ill-motivated.

Strange answers here focusing on my typing skills, rather than on the fact it sometimes makes sense to uncluster repetetive lines with always the same content with the help of a simple which actually improves readability. Image having hundreds of those value lines, seeing through them is a lot easier, when having them orderly structered visible.

@Brainiac - If you have so many member variables that you get tired typing them all in, that is the problem you should try to solve. Not by hiding the code, but by making the classes smaller.

"it sometimes makes sense to uncluster repetetive lines" we can't tell because you didn't describe the real problem. It is so unlikely and rare that it seems more likely that you're doing it wrong, so we're asking you what the real problem is.

Not exactly the same syntax, but you can define a type alias to give the class name something that's always the same.
It's not possible to define a macro inside a macro.  An alternative, used when the macros are very complex, is to #define some parameters that will be used and then #include a header file containing macro definitions.  Then the parameters can be redefined and header included again.
#include <string>
template <typename T> class Base {};
template <typename T> struct Value {};
template <typename T, typename Container>
Value<T> value(Value<T> Container::*, const T&);

#define BASE(name) \
  class name: public Base<name> { \
    using ThisClass = name;
#define ENDBASE(name) }

#define VALUE(name, type, init) \
  Value<type> name = value<type>(&ThisClass::name, init)
 
BASE(MyClass)
  VALUE(testString, std::string, "something");
ENDBASE(MyClass);


But why would you ever do this???

Thank you. I solved it not using directly your approach, but instead included the typedef into the Base class, not into the macro which solved the trick.

@PasserBy I use it order to 1st save myself some work with writing hundreds of ´Value name = ...` lines, and 2nd it improves readability a lot.

@TrentP - Not the downvoter, but this is just totally ugly. We should not tell people how to write code that stinks. Not even if they ask for it. And apparently, the real problem is that there are hundreds of member variables. That is the problem that needs to be solved!

"Why take your disapproval out on me?" because the result is terrible code, regardless of how the whole thing started.
